# How to set an image as DataGrid header background?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

Below is my `DataGrid` xaml which is bound to a datasource.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="240" Name="dtDemo"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LfdConnections}">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridCell}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Monitor" Width="55" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=MonitorName}" Height="28" Name="lblMonitorName" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Connection" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConnTypes,Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0">
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Port/IP" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PortTypes,Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              SelectedIndex="0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LfdIds,Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              SelectedIndex="0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Source" Width="130" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceTypes,Mode=OneTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                              SelectedIndex="0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Connect" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Connect" Height="23" Name="btnConnect" Width="75" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I want to add an `image` as the column header in this `DataGrid`. Can you please tell how to do this?

Comment: do you want to set image as background or add is as part of a header?

Comment: You should style the DataGridColumnHeader template to your needs. Either you can search for the template style on the msdn website or try and use Expression Blend to get it.

Comment: @dkozl I want the image as background.

Comment: @Santux I don't have Expression Blend. :(

Comment: You can have a look at the template style here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066(v=vs.95).aspx

It can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below snippet

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
      <Grid>
         <Image Source="C:\Users\Vimal\Desktop\1.jpg" />
         <TextBlock Text="Monitor"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Grid>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old question, but if it can be useful for someone, I had to make some changes to Vimal's answer. Here is my code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="EstadoSinc" CanUserSort="False" MinWidth="60" Width="60" MaxWidth="60" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/Sincronizar.png" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=IdEstadoSincronizacion}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```